# PHP 7 já tem versão estável para produção?

Tags: php, php-7

Estou pensando em construir uma nova versão do sistema atual da minha empresa, ele está com o PHP na versão 5.5.9.

O PHP 7 já tem versão estável para trabalhar em produção? Vi muitos *posts* na internet mas ninguém falou em estabilidade.

Comment: Eu tenho o 7 a correr em modo de teste no servidor da empresa e por enquanto não tenho queixa nenhuma.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Quando fica na dúvida sobre informações espalhadas na internet e não dá para ter certeza se são verdadeiras (com toda razão) o que devemos fazer? Procurar o local oficial pra ver se lá tem alguma coisa.

Então vamos no [site do PHP](http://php.net/) e vemos que lá fala sim da versão 7, já tem alguns *releases* extras. Já está no [7.1](http://php.net/downloads.php#v7.1.0) no momento desta resposta.

Se não estivesse estável não haveria uma versão oficial. É claro que sempre pode ter algum problema, pode ter incompatibilidades. Tem que decidir se vai conviver com isso ou não. Tem muita gente usando ele, tem quem já decidiu **não** usar, provavelmente pelas incompatibilidades, e [são muitas](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.incompatible.php). Ou seja, como tudo, você tem que decidir por conta própria o que é melhor para você.

Ela [tem melhorias também](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.php).

Note que estabilidade e maturidade são coisas diferentes. Há concordância por parte dos desenvolvedores e comunidade que o PHP 7 está pronto para uso. Não quer dizer que ele ainda não tenha problemas, demora para obter maturidade e realmente estar tudo em ordem. Alguns produtos passam anos e não se tornam maduros.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 5):

Sim, o PHP 7 é estável já [faz mais de um ano](http://php.net/releases/7_0_0.php), lançado em [5 de dezembro de 2015](http://www.php.net/ChangeLog-7.php#7.0.0). Atualmente a [última versão estável é a 7.1](http://php.net/ChangeLog-7.php#7.1.0), lançado em dezembro desse ano.

Para atualizar para a versão mais recente, pode ocorrer algumas incompatibilidades. A mais impactante pode ser a [remoção da antiga extensão do `mysql_*`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php), descontinuada [desde o PHP 5.5](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/migration55.deprecated.php). 
Para mais detalhes, como você está na versão 5.5, veja o *upgrade guide* para a [versão 5.6](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/migration56.php) e em seguida para as versões [7.0](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/migration70.php) e [7.1](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/migration71.php).

Você pode acompanhar o status do suporte das versões do PHP [aqui](http://php.net/supported-versions.php). Inclusive a versão que você está utilizando não tem mais suporte nem pra atualizações de segurança (o que já é um motivo para migrar).

[image: Versões suportadas do PHP]

Além da questão de segurança, o PHP 7 traz grandes melhorias de desempenho e consumo de memória, sendo [executado em até 75% mais rápido](http://www.zend.com/en/resources/php7_infographic) que a versão 5.6.

Com isso, recomendo a todos que busquem utilizar a versão estável mais recente, a não ser que exista um motivo sério para não fazer isso (ter que adaptar o código devido a *breaking changes* não é um motivo sério xD).